# Form value second time not visible when displayed with jQuery ui dialog

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm displaying some form data in a jquery dialog. Everything works fine when I do this the first time. I can see the "my value" string in the dialog. If I reopen the dialog again for the second time the form value is no longer visible. Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jUtVv/1/) to try it out yourself. This is the code:

```
var dialog;

$("#b1").click(function(){
dialog = $("<div></div>").html("<p><input id='input1' type='text'></p>").dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
});
$("#input1").val("my value");
dialog.dialog("open");
});
```

This bug only happens when I add the html tags dynamically. If I use a static html block everything works fine. Any idea what is wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are not destroying the old

```
<input id='input1' type='text'>
```

so when you call

```
$("#input1").val("my value");
```

it sets the value of first

```
<input id='input1' type='text'>
```

it finds in the DOM.

Comment: I did some more research on this. When you load html content into your dom via $("#myelem").html() each time you click somewhere the content gets overwritten and everything works fine. But when you create a dialog from content inside #myelem jquery moves the myelem to the end of the body for proper stacking if more than one dialog is around. The next time you load your content you will have a second #myelem. The .dialog("destroy") will not clean up this mess as it only removes it's dialog html nodes. Working with dyn. content and dialog means -> clean up yourself!